# How to improve time spent on end to end testing using codeceptjs?

Tags: e2e-testing, codeceptjs

we are using codeceptjs for e2e tests for my work. For every code submission, we run these tests (we use webpack-dev-server to mock the backend).

In the beginning, the time spent to run these tests is acceptable. However after 1 year we have around 900 tests (i.e. CodeCept's Scenarios) and it takes around 1 hour to finish. Basically after finishing a feature we add some tests and for bugs we also add e2e test. We realize this is not sustainable if we keep adding more e2e tests since it takes to long to run. Do you have any suggestions how can I improve them ( we are using codeceptjs ) ?

I am thinking about only running some e2e tests for important features for each submission, the rests should be run separately ( maybe once per day ). Thanks.

Comment: I'm not familiar with codeceptjs , but what about parallelization? run on different nodes or processes

Comment: Thanks @ujlbu4, parallelization seems to be good idea.